# Read data continuously via serial communication

Tags: c#

I am creating an application that communicates serially.

We have created a single data transmission/reception process, but actually we need to read multiple data.

However, when sending multiple data as shown below, data reception processing starts during loop processing.

```
    public void Send()
    {
        if (!_serialPort.IsOpen) return;

        try
        {
            var setDataIds = new string[]
            {
                // Test Send Data A
                "04-02-43-33-30-20-41-03",
                 // Test Send Data B
                 "04-02-43-33-33-20-41-03",
                 // Test Send Data C
                 "04-02-43-33-36-20-41-03",
            };

            foreach(var id in setDataIds)
            {
                var tmp = id.Split("-").Select(hex => Convert.ToByte(hex, 16));
                byte[] sendData = tmp.ToArray();
               _serialPort.Write(sendData, 0, sendData.Length);
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Therefore, the next data transmission is performed without judging whether the received data is the correct value.

I want to check the result of each data transmission before processing the next data transmission, but I can't think of a way to do that.

In other words, if the result of A's data transmission is normal, I want to send B's data, and if B's ​​data is normal, I want to send C's data.

I'm sorry if the explanation is difficult to understand.
I would like some advice.

Code

```
        private  SerialPort _serialPort = null;

        public bool PortOpen(string comNum)
        {
            _serialPort ??= new SerialPort
            {
                PortName = comNum,
                BaudRate = 9600,
                DataBits = 8,
                Parity = Parity.None,
                StopBits = StopBits.One,
                Handshake = Handshake.None,
                Encoding = Encoding.UTF8,
                WriteTimeout = 100000,
                ReadTimeout = 100000,
                NewLine = "\r\n",
            };

            _serialPort.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(EventReciveAsync);

            if (!_serialPort.IsOpen)
            {
                try
                {
                    _serialPort.Open();
                }
                catch(Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                    return false;
                }
            }
            return true;
        }


    public void Send()
    {
        if (!_serialPort.IsOpen) return;

        try
        {
            var setDataIds = new string[]
            {
                // Test Send Data A
                "04-02-43-33-30-20-41-03",
                 // Test Send Data B
                 "04-02-43-33-33-20-41-03",
                 // Test Send Data C
                 "04-02-43-33-36-20-41-03",
            };

            foreach(var id in setDataIds)
            {
                var tmp = id.Split("-").Select(hex => Convert.ToByte(hex, 16));
                byte[] sendData = tmp.ToArray();
               _serialPort.Write(sendData, 0, sendData.Length);
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
    }



    public void EventReciveAsync(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!_serialPort.IsOpen) return;

        var srtDataReceived = "";
        var buf = new byte[_serialPort.BytesToRead];

        try
        {
            _serialPort.Read(buf, 0, buf.Length);
            srtDataReceived = BitConverter.ToString(buf);
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }

        if (_serialPort.IsOpen)
        {
            //Process to check data
        }
    }
```

Comment: this is quite a big question, there are different approaches. Basically you would need a mapping of output to correct received input, and some sort of a manager class that keeps track of the outgoing and incoming information

Comment: This is difficult... I can imagine how to modify the received data (although I can't think of the code...) Perhaps it means checking for missing data or determining the start and end characters? I just can't imagine the part of tracking data. Does this link the sent data with the received data?

Comment: The DataReceived event does not help you implement this.  So don't use it, call Read() after you called Write().  If that causes unacceptable delays in the user interface then move the code into a Task.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply.
Thanks for your comment.

Since many samples used DataReceived, I thought I had to use this to receive data.
DataReceived is just something that can be triggered by reception.
Is this correct?

Comment: "DataReceived is just something that can be triggered by reception. Is this correct?" yes this is correct, but then you would need to create you own chain of events which should lead to the sending of the next command. This would be an event based approach